# Vector Function Differentiation: $f(\vec x) = (\vec x - \vec y)^T(\vec x - \vec y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, vector-analysis

I am currently self-studying to learn vector calculus. Would the following be correct:

If $f(\vec x) = (\vec x - \vec y)^T(\vec x - \vec y)$, then I can rewrite it as $(\vec x - \vec y)^2$ since it is just the dot product of a vector with itself.

Which means if I want to find the derivative as follows:

$\frac{\partial f(\vec x)}{\partial \vec x} = 2(\vec x - \vec y)$

Is that correct? I simply just used the chain rule as I would do on normal scalar functions.

Comment: And what would $(\vec x-\vec y)^3$ mean, then? No, you can’t rewrite the original expression as a power of $(\vec x-\vec y)$ and then apply the single-variable rule to it, even though you end up with the same result _in this specific case_.